# How to use binding for value in x:Double tag in uwp?

Tags: uwp-xaml

I use a static resource for opacity of various controls in my uwp page, resource named 'BgOpacity2'. When I use a constant value like 0.8, it works. But it shows error as 'Invalid value for type Double..', when I use 'x:Bind' as shown below. How to handle this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set bind for x:Double like the above. That is wrong xaml syntax. In general, if you want to modify static resource value you could modify it in the code behind like following.

```
Application.Current.Resources["BgOpacity2"] = 0.8;
```

You could also create a `Setting` class that contain such property. for more detail, please refer this [case reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50291418/different-font-size-for-specific-device/50341584#50341584).